# Superlevel sets of a probability density

Tags: probability, reference-request, probability-distributions

Let $f$ be a probability density, and let $\alpha$ be a given value between 0 and 1.  There must exist some value $q(\alpha)$ such that the set $\{x:f(x)\geq q(\alpha)\}$ has a mass of $\alpha$.  Is there a special name for the superlevel sets of a probability density like this?  It also occurs to me that the area/volume of these regions (instead of the mass) would be a useful quantity because it would describe how "clustered" the density is. Is there a name for that?

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $f$, the pdf of a random variable $X$, has inverses on a finite sequence of sets $A_i$ and $\cup_{i=1}^nA_i=\mathbb R$. Let $F$ be the corresponding cdf. Then consider a value $$v=f(F^{-1}(1-\alpha)), \ 0\le \alpha\le1.$$

With these notations, the "mass" of $\{x:f(x)\geq q(\alpha)\}$ is $P(f(X)\geq q(\alpha))$ and let $q(\alpha)=v$. So we have for the "mass":

$$P(f(X)\ge v)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}P(f(X)\ge v|X\in A_i)P(X\in A_i)=$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}P(X\ge f^{-1}(v)|X\in A_i)P(X\in A_i)=$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}(1-F(f^{-1}(v)))P(X\in A_i)=1-F(f^{-1}(v)).$$
Substituting $f(F^{-1}(1-\alpha))$ for $v$ we get
$$1-F(f^{-1}(v))=1-F(f^{-1}(f(F^{-1}(1-\alpha))))=\alpha.$$

As far as the importance, and the name of something like this, unfortunately I don't know.